# Python analog for Groovy's it?

Tags: python, groovy, syntactic-sugar

Groovy has nice syntax for simple clojures, which eliminates the need to explitly name 
the single parameter. It will be named *it* by default.

```
def closure = { print it }
closure( "hi there" ) //prints "hi there"
```

What is the best way to emulate *it* magikal parameter in Python?

Example of what I want:

```
>>> it = It()
>>> print map(it + 5, [1, 2, 3])
[6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: So what is the expected input and output?

Comment: No, Python does not have an implicit 'first argument' for lambdas or functions. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am surely know, that Python can't do that. I am looking for some trick to do something similar.

Comment: @uhbif19: But what actual problem are you trying to solve? Groovy's implicit first argument only saves you having to add `it -> ` to your closures. Python's syntax is already very readable, just more explicit (explicitly so).

Comment: Python syntax is too verbose for use in long pipes.

Comment: Perhaps you are applying the wrong paradigms to your Python code? Python isn't *that* suitable to *only* do functional programming in.

Comment: For the Groovy sample code `{ print " ${it}" }` given, surely you can just use the function name `print` since all that closure does is prints the `it` argument. There's no need for closure syntax at all, let alone a use case for an implied argument name. So if you were calling a function called `doIt`, instead of, say, `doIt{print"${it}"}` you could instead write `doIt(print)`.

Comment: @VorgvanGeir It is just an example.

Comment: Please look, whether it is possible reopen this question.

The question was closed due to "unclear what you are asking".

Now I have add some examples, improve the description, and finally find the great anwser. I think now my question is very clear, and it is ready to return on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I have found the exact anwser on my question. This is the library fn.py which implements _ magikal variable and some usable functional programming conceptions.

Example of use:

```
>>> from fn import _
>>> list(map(_ * 2, range(5)))
[0,2,4,6,8]
```

Answer (score 3):

You just give your lambda or function an *explicit* first argument:

```
lambda it: ' {}'.format(it)
```

This fits with the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit

Answer (score 0):

My first thougt is to do some magikal *it* object with magik methods producing curryied function.

```
class It :
    def __add__(self, another_one) :
         return lambda x: x + another_one



it = It()
print map(it + 5, [1, 2, 3])
```